# Resized swap partition - swap space does not change?

Tags: swap

Recently I resized my swap partition to make it bigger, but swap space staid the same. Why is that so and how can I change it?

Here is what I get when I run swapon:

```
swapon: /dev/sda6: pagesize=4096, swapsize=999292928, devsize=3798990848
```

Comment: how did you resize the swap partition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to re-setup the swap partition, even if it was resized there's a step missing.

Turn off swap first:

```
sudo swapoff /dev/sda6
```

Reinitialize it:

```
sudo mkswap /dev/sda6
```

Then reenable it:

```
sudo swapon -a
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped. For other users: mkswap generated new UUID, so I needed to modify /etc/fstab. Again, thanks a lot!